# System.InvalidOperationException The Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) required by the XAML Designer was not correctly installed.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have uninstalled and then reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 Community twice now, and whenever i start the program after creating a 'univeral Windows App' in C# i get the error

**'System.InvalidOperationException
The Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) required by the XAML Designer was not correctly installed. Consider repairing your installation of either Visual Studio or the Windows SDK.'**

I reinstalled Visual Studio Community with the SDK first, and after that did not work, I then installed Visual Studio Community 2015 Community on its own, and then downloaded the SDK afterwards.

However, when i run the application on my local machine the app runs fine with no errors.

I was wondering if anybody had a solution for this issue?

Comment: no solution, but that same problem here... >.<

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by updating Visual Studio's tools and updating the Windows SDK to the Windows 10 Anniversary  Update SDK, build 14393.

After I updated the XAML designer was not bringing up any errors regarding an incorrect installation of either Visual Studio or the Windows 10 SDK